# Will C# compiler strip out empty methods?

Tags: c#, compilation

I put a debug print codes everywhere when I am fixing codes, when I am done with it I did not remove them but put a comment so that when the bug occurs around here next I would be able to uncomment it and get it to print out data.

(I can't get used to breakpoint debugging and inspecting variables, and I found putting debug print I can get the timing that I want the message to appear better.)

If possible I would like to be able to switch the debug code on and off more easily but since they are all spread out, commenting/uncommenting is a pain. Putting `#if` preprocessor should work but a one line debug print becomes 3 lines `#if` `Debug` `#endif` everywhere.

So I have an idea to wrap the debug method with my own, and inside it is just `#if` check before the actual debug method. My question is when the `#if` directive is false the function becomes empty, will the compiled code still jumps to this empty function? I am worried especially if this empty method is in a core game loop and being called multiple thousand times per seconds.

Also if it really get stripped out, I wonder if the parameter data remains in the program? For example if I write `MyDebug("Encryption key : " + key);` will that string remains in the code if the method is empty?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compiler won't strip out empty methods because it has no way of knowing that they won't be called (even if they are private - due to reflection).

However you can use [`ConditionalAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to do this the same way as .Net does for `Debug.WriteLine()` etc:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public static void MyDebugOnlyMethod()
{
    ...
}
```

This will cause the compiler to omit from the compiled code that method and all calls to it, unless the "DEBUG" conditional symbol is defined at compile time.

This is a bit more readable than using #if DEBUG ... #endif

Also note that you don't have to use "DEBUG" - you can use any other string that you want, but you would than have to define it when needed using `#define` or by setting a conditional compilation symbol in the project settings.

Comment: I have never known an attribute could affect compilation too! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the best practice is inserting the code in debug mode region:

```
#if DEBUG
  //your code here
#endif
```

and it will compile and work only in debug mode

Comment: Yes this is what I mean by "Putting #if preprocessor should work but a one line debug print becomes 3 lines #if Debug #endif everywhere." It make the code looks dirty because I have so many debugs throughout the code...

Comment: can you give an example of your code, it's sounds like you should add a unit test to your application that will test your code

Comment: Yes unit test is a good idea but it is exactly the failing unit test that I needs to inspect what went wrong deep inside with a debug print. Anyway I got the answer I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Three ways:

1) to check whether debugger is attached or not.

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached){
 // do }
```

2) To know if debugging, everywhere in program. Declare global variable.

```
bool isOnDebug=false;
```

Create function for checking debug mode.

```
[ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]
public static void isOnDebugMethod()
{
    isOnDebug = true;
}
```

In the initialize method call the function

```
isOnDebugMethod();
```

3) #if preprocessor directive

```
#if DEBUG
private /*static*/ bool  bisdegug= false;
#endif
```